# Is there a way to remove a connection in Asteroid without closing the client and starting over?

Tags: augmented-reality, developer-tools

I'm working on creating the guess your age reaction in Asteroid, and I connected the patches incorrectly. I got it working after having to close and restart the project from scratch, I'm sure there's a simpler way but I'm still new to it.

this is what I'm talking about asteroid.zone

Answer (score 0):

Update: I figured it out, if you double click on the right hand side of the patch you included then the connection automatically disappears.